# How to put image on the top of the div?

Tags: html, css, image

here is my code

```
<div id="content_main2">
    <div id="content_main2_left"><img src="../images/logo.png"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
#content_main2
{
    width:800px;
    height:200px;
}
#content_main2_left
{
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    height:240px;
    margin-top:-40px;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px;
    -moz-border-radius:15px;
    border-radius:15px;
    background:#817339; 
}
```

my result

[image]

bt i need to display logo on top of the div. I mean half on `#content_main2` div and another half on `#content_main2_left`. how can i do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

write `margin-top:-40px` for image, not for div.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with negative margins.

Answer (score 1):

Better use

```
position: absolute;
```

and 
   different `z-index` both

Answer (score 0):

for image use the following css

```
#logoimage
{
   position: absolute;
   bottom: xxpx;
}
```

replace **xx** with required pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this rule to your stylesheet:

```
#content_main2_left img
{
    position: relative;
    left: 235px;
}
```

I'm confused about how you want it to overlap though.